# Idiom or phrase to indicate sadness

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language, idiom-request

Is there any idiom or phrase to better express **sadness** in the context of the following sentence

> This is a **sad and unfortunate** murder case which involves the death of a two-year old child.

Comment: [desperately unfortunate](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22desperately+unfortunate%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJgrnXu4zuAhWJxoUKHZG0AboQ_AUoA3oECAYQBQ&biw=1440&bih=821&dpr=2)?

Comment: There are thousands of ways to describe the death of a child as sad in English. There’s no way to narrow down the list without more information about why you don’t want to use “sad and unfortunate”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found in [Gngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sad%20and%20unfortunate%2Ctragic%20and%20terrible&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csad%20and%20unfortunate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctragic%20and%20terrible%3B%2Cc0) that

> Tragic and terrible

is more used than

> sad and unfortunate

***Tragic and terrible*** is stronger than your phrase, but I think it does apply in the given context.